# @Autowired not working in spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In service implementation,with help of `@Autowired` i am injecting `CollectInfo`  object in serviceImpl but i am getting `NullPointerException`.

```
package net.group.cts.service.serviceImpl;
       @Service
        public class EmployeeImpl implements EmployeeService {       
            @Autowired
            CollectInfo  info;

            public void processData(){
                info.getName();
            }
        }

package net.group.cts.model;
    @Component
    public class CollectInfo  (){

        String name;

        public String getName(){
            name = name + "Mr.";
            return name;}
        }

    }
```

Xmlconfig.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="net.group.cts"/>
<bean id="info"    class="net.group.emp.model.CollectInfo  "/>
```

Comment: can you share CollectInfo  class.check if you have annotated the class with @Component

Comment: Is `EmployeeImpl` spring container managed?

Comment: @Vikram yes i defined

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject a bean in a class if this class is not a Spring bean.
`EmployeeImpl` is not annotated with any [Spring bean stereotype](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html) such as `@Component` or `@Service`.

Add one of them on `EmployeeImpl` and ensure that the two classes are located inside the package scanned by Spring `<context:component-scan base-package="net.group.emp.service"/>`
 and it should be ok.

Besides, both annotating a bean with @Component :

```
@Component
public class CollectInfo  (){...}
```

and configuring it in the Spring xml configuration :

```
<bean id="info"  class="net.group.emp.model.CollectInfo  "/>
```

is redundant. 
It will finally create two beans : one name `collectInfo` and another named `info`.

I advise you to favor annotation over xml configuration as it is possible (it is the very most of cases).

Comment: i cant remove this <bean id="info"    class="net.group.emp.model.CollectInfo  "/> from xml bcoz am using it for gateway purpose which working fine.